# How can I write a function to take the mean in a survey?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement

Hello I am attempting to write a code/function that can give me the mean/average of a set of scores for each data sets, but I need some help.

Below is an example. I need this function to give me the sum of the scores. The participant could select on a scale of 0-101. But for numbers 2, 5 , and 6. I need to take the reverse score. Lastly I need to take the mean. So the score divided by 6.
**The expected outcome (the answer) the score = 226 and the mean is 37.667**

| data | Question | Scores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ''I feel tense'' | 76 |
| 2 | ''I am calm'' | 90 |
| 3 | ''I am excited'' | 52 |
| 4 | ''I am worried'' | 65 |
| 5 | ''I am satisfied'' | 90 |
| 6 | ''I am relaxed'' | 90 |

The problem is I need to code to be universal so I can use it for each data set I have. Because the questions for each participant is given in random order. For example (number one ''I feel tense'') can be in the 5 position and so forth. Thus I am thinking I need a if else statement, but I am a total beginner in R. maybe (if ''I am calm'', do this else do this etc.? )

I have a code that I wrote that works! but it is not very universal because I have to go in a change each data set to match the questions. I would really appreciate some insight or help writing this function.

---

My code that works for one data set, its kinda long and bad looking. Also its based on the actual data I am working on in Excell that's why its named different.(Data c and data w is just giving me access to the specific places I wanted )

```
Data_c = DATA1$choice #Change here! 
Data_w = DATA2$word
```

I have to Change each Question based on if I need the score to be reversed or not. I commented out what I do not use.

```
Q1 = abs(Data_c[1]-101)
#Q1 = (Data_c[1])

#Q2 = abs(Data_c[2]-101)
Q2 = (Data_c[2])

Q3 = abs(Data_c[3]-101)
#Q3 = (Data_c[3])

Q4 = abs(Data_c[4]-101)
#Q4 = (Data_c[4])

#Q5 = abs(Data_c[5]-101)
Q5 = (Data_c[5])

#Q6 = abs(Data_c[6]-101)
Q6 = (Data_c[6])

df1 <- data.frame(Questions = Data_w,scores = c(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6))

sum = df1$scores[1]+df1$scores[2]+df1$scores[3]+
df1$scores[4]+df1$scores[5]+df1$scores[6]

A = mean(sum/6)
```

Thank you in advance for reading this and insight

Comment: I don’t understand how these scores are supposed to sum up to 62. Relatedly, it’s also unclear what you mean by “reverse score”: 101 - score?

Comment: Your code replaces the function `sum` with a variable. *Never* use variable names that correspond to functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you need a key that will define, whether the statement score is reversed. Note that the order of the responses is irrelevant in the key, but all possible responses from `dat` must be represented in `key`.

```
key <- read.table(text = " Question Reversed
1 'I am calm' FALSE
2 'I am excited' TRUE
3 'I feel tense' TRUE
4 'I am worried' TRUE
5 'I am satisfied' FALSE
6 'I am relaxed' FALSE", header = TRUE)
```

Then you need to select the correct order of the responses with respect to the key. This can be done with the `match` function.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "data Question Scores
1 'I feel tense' 76
2 'I am calm' 90
3 'I am excited' 52
4 'I am worried' 65
5 'I am satisfied' 90
6 'I am relaxed' 90", header = TRUE)

dat$Reversed = key$Reversed[match(dat$Question, key$Question)]
```

Since a `TRUE/FALSE` variable is essentially a `1/0`, we can use that to calculate the mean directly from the product of the two alternative functions.

```
res <- sum(dat$Score * dat$Reversed, (101 - dat$Score) * !dat$Reversed) / nrow(dat)
```

The exclamation mark in the `(101 - dat$Score) * !dat$Reversed)` is important, because it negates the `TRUE/FALSE` indicators.

Comment: This is great! But I am having a hard time alternating my code. In R, I am working with CSV file instead of a table. Can you explain how to change this so it can run? I tried reading the read table function but I'm still at a lost. - thank you

Comment: key <- read.csv(file = STAI_BA06DI26_1st_A_1st$word , " Question Reversed .... etc) 
I tried this and a few others, sorry if this seems like a basic question

Comment: @Rose Your problem with reading the table is likely in the file name and a separator. The separator in csv files is usually ",", but can be ";" on some computers. The filename should be a character vector. Try something like `read.table(file = "filename.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")`.

Comment: Ah Yes! It runs this way, but now how can I access my questions like this? Do I just put them in the code? like maybe key <- read.table(file = "STAI_BA06DI26_1st_A_1st.csv", 
1 'I am calm.' FALSE
2 'I feel tense' TRUE
3 'I am excited' TRUE
4 'I am worried' TRUE
5 'I am satisfied' FALSE
6 'I am relaxed' FALSE, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

Comment: @Rose The code you write will not work. What do you mean by accessing the questions? Perhaps, try to modify your questions so that it will represent better what you need to do.

Comment: thank you! I got it to work now. I had to modify my questions like you said.

Answer (score 2):

I created two functions one takes the question numbers for reversing and another take the actual questions for reversing. With these functions, you can automate your code.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "data Question Scores
1 'I feel tense' 76
2 'I am calm' 90
3 'I am excited' 52
4 'I am worried' 65
5 'I am satisfied' 90
6 'I am relaxed' 90", header = TRUE)

mean_of_scores_num <- function(df, reverse_data){
  df %>% 
    filter(data %in% reverse_data) %>% 
    pull(Scores) %>% 
    append(101 -df %>% 
             filter(!data %in% reverse_data) %>% 
             pull(Scores)) %>% 
    mean()
}

mean_of_scores_ques <- function(df, reverse_question){
  df %>% 
    filter(Question %in% reverse_question) %>% 
    pull(Scores) %>% 
    append(101 -df %>% 
             filter(!Question %in% reverse_question) %>% 
             pull(Scores)) %>% 
    mean()
}

mean_of_scores_num(df, c(1,3,5))
#> [1] 46

mean_of_scores_ques(df, c('I am relaxed', 'I am worried'))
#> [1] 41.83333
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>